# Poor X Windows performance

Tags: window-manager, unix, x11, xquartz

I use Macs a lot to host applications running on Linux boxes via X Windows, but tend to find that, after some period of time, I can no longer open new X Windows clients on the Mac - I get messages like:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:103.0
```

This can occur even when I am attempting to launch the application from an existing X Windows client (eg an xterm).

My X server is XQuartz 2.7.4, but I have this problem when using the native X Windows support also.

**Update**: Just to make it clear, I am using ssh with X forwarding to log in to the remote host eg ssh -X remote_host

Comment: Are you setting the DISPLAY environment variable?

Comment: No, I am doing things like ssh -X host so shouldn't need to - need to update the question to make that clear...

Comment: The fact that the display number is so high is suspicious. In my case it does not grow. I would in any case suggest to use a trusted connection (`-Y` instead of `-X`)

Comment: Are you ssh to localhost?

Comment: No remote hosts